# Using cardano-wallet for ingame sign in

Tags: wallet

i have built an in game User interface around Cardano-wallet.
now im looking for a way to let the player sign in using his wallet .

how can i approach it using cardano-wallet?
is there a way to let the player sign some data using his private key , then on the server side i decode it using his public key ?

( one of the solutions i tried is to let the player send 1 ADA from his wallet to a server provided address , and i monitor the transaction to verify ... but bad approach obviously ..)

thank you for your attention.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

will wait for message sign / verify gets added to cardano-wallet api itself ,
https://github.com/input-output-hk/cardano-wallet/issues/3537
implementing it from scratch or doing other hacky ways will be inconvenient.

Answer (score 0):

If your game is not browser based, one way to do this is to create a small website on which you let the user sign a message with a browser based wallet. The website can then send the signed message to your server.

To do this you can use the [signData() method as specified in CIP-30](https://cips.cardano.org/cips/cip30/#apisigndataaddraddresspayloadbytespromisedatasignature).

Or if you have the private key of the user's wallet in your game, you can sign a message in your game and send it to the server.

On your server, you have to verify that the message is signed correctly. You can do this using the [cardano-serialization-lib](https://developers.cardano.org/docs/get-started/cardano-serialization-lib/overview/). More details on message signing can be found in [CIP-8](https://cips.cardano.org/cips/cip8/).

If the message is signed correctly, you can return something like an access token (e.g. a [JWT](https://jwt.io)) to the user.

---

This is a very simple example on how this could work and there are a lot of things you'd need to consider when you implement this like franken-address attacks or token lifetimes etc.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion , i was looking for a way that wont force the user to leave the game or get interrupted from his virtual experience ( could be VR , PS5 , anywhere.. ) . https://github.com/input-output-hk/cardano-wallet/issues/3537 having the message sign-in / verify added to the cardano-wallet api itself , would do the trick. happpy to wait for that .